# Ajax with symfony UrlHelper

Tags: ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I use an UrlHelper to perform a delete action, like so:

`<?php echo link_to('delete', '@foo_delete?id=' . $foo->id, array('method'=>'DELETE'))?>`

Which generates all sorts of magic javascript output, and it works.

Now I'm wondering, is there an easy way to use the UrlHelper to do the same thing ajax style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link_to_remote` from Symfony 1.0 became deprecated.
So instead, you can install the [sfJqueryReloadedPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin) and use the `jq_link_to_remote()`

```
<?php use_helper('jQuery');

<?php echo jq_link_to_remote('delete', array(
  'url' => '@foo_delete?id=1', 
  'confirm' => 'Are you sure?', 
  'csrf' => 1, 
  'method' => 'delete')) ?>
```

But, there is a problem with this: `sfJqueryReloadedPlugin` does not support the DELETE method, so what you can do is a small change on the plugin. In  `plugins/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/lib/helper/jQueryHelper.php`where you read:

```
if ((isset($options['method'])) && (strtoupper($options['method']) == 'GET')) $method = $options['method'];
```

should be:

```
if ((isset($options['method'])) && (strtoupper($options['method']) == 'GET' || strtoupper($options['method']) == 'DELETE')) $method = $options['method'];
```

(just proposed this change to the plugin developers)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can ;-)

Here is a simple sceleton for your action :

```
/* is it an AJAX request ? */
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
    /* do what you want to do */

    /* Text as result */
    return $this->renderText("All worked well with ajax");
}
```

Of course you may use JSON as return, specific HTTP Header or some other improvements. This depends on your JS implementation.

All is documented very well :

- [Jobjeet Tutorial Day 18:
  AJAX](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/18)